# How to use Selector to pass two arguments with function

Tags: ios, swift, selector

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I am trying to pass switch selection and string to selector function but I am not able to. Please help.

```
let pidName = "someString"
cell.switchSelection.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.switchSelection.addTarget(self, action: 
 #selector(self.switchOperation(_:pid:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Here I have to pass sender and `pidName` but failing

```
@objc func switchOperation(_ sender: UISwitch, pid: Any){
     let store = (sender).isOn
     let settingTag = pid
}
```

Comment: Remember to remove the target in case of cell reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to move the action into your cell class:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var switchSelection: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        switchSelection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyCell.action(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func configure(switchAction: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        self.switchAction = switchAction
    }

    @objc func action(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        switchAction(sender.isOn)
    }

    private var switchAction: (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }
}
```

Now in your table view delegate, you can just do this:

```
let pidName = "someString"
cell.configure(switchAction: { [weak self] isOn in 
    let store = isOn 
    let settingTag = pid
}
```

or you could do:

```
let pidName = "someString"
cell.configure(switchAction: { [weak self] isOn in 
    self?.switchOperation(isOn: isOn, pid: pid)
}

@objc func switchOperation(isOn: Bool, pid: Any){
    let store = isOn
    let settingTag = pid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have another parameter as

```
cell.switchSelection.addTarget(self, action: 
#selector(self.switchOperation(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

only sends one paramter of the same type as the object the target is added to

you need to set tag of the switch someWhere to `pid` and use it like this

```
@objc func switchOperation(_ sender: UISwitch) {
   print(sender.tag)
}
```

Comment: This is the exact answer.